# What happens if you Apparate without a license?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

What happens if you Apparate correctly without a license? Is there any way to detect Apparitions without licenses as there are to detect Underage magic?

Comment: You get sent to Azkaban

Comment: You break the law

Comment: @Richard no you don't i think. you just get heavily fined or something..you won't get sent to azkaban for a small thing like that

Comment: I think there's a flaw here. You can get your Apparition license at 16, but in order to Apparate, you need to not be an underage wizard. It's like getting your license, but not having a car (poor analogy). Harry even says later on that he DOES have his license for it.

Comment: Apparition license IS NOT given at 16 years age, they are just taught at that age how to apparate (that too when they are turning 17 soon). Apparition license is only given after you pass Ministry test once you are OVERAGE. Side-along-apparition does not require license (as in case of harry with dumbledore), but pure apparition does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### There can't be any way to detect Apparition without a license.

For the simple reason that Harry successfully Apparated multiple times in *HP and the Deathly Hallows* without a license: he was too young to get one when Ron and Hermione did their tests. In fact, he even Apparated undetected in *HP and the Half-Blood Prince*, when taking a weakened Dumbledore from the sea cave back to Hogwarts.

### But if you *do* get caught doing so, you get fined.

> "You have to pass a test to Apparate?" Harry asked.
>
> "Oh yes," said Mr Weasley, tucking the tickets safely into the back pocket of his jeans. "The Department of Magical transportation had to fine a couple of people the other day for Apparating without a licence. It's not easy, Apparition, and when it's not done properly it can lead to nasty complications. This pair I'm talking about went and splinched themselves."
>
> [...]
>
> Harry had a sudden vision of a pair of legs and an eyeball lying abandoned on the pavement of Privet Drive.
>
> "Were they OK?" he asked, startled.
>
> "Oh yes," said Mr Weasley matter-of-factly. "But they got a heavy fine, and I don't think they'll be trying it again in a hurry. You don't mess around with Apparition."
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Goblet of Fire*</sub>

Comment: Damn, beat me to it :)

Comment: @DVK FGitW ;-) Also found a nice quote to finish off the answer.

Comment: You ninja'd me with the quote as well ... +1 :P

Comment: Shouldn't have bothered with that damn citation ... Ah well, you win some ... :P

Comment: I Therefore asked "Correctly" ..if some 17+ wizard/witch tried to apparate and did it correctly (Probably a fred and george kind of thing), Would the ministry detect i?

Comment: @prakharlondhe Doesn't the first part of my answer answer that question?

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the heading :)..

Comment: @prakharlondhe Harry *wasn't* an underage wizard at that time ...

Comment: sorry, edited the comment accordingly.. i am a highly confused person :)

Comment: then what is the need of license? If you can't detect a correctly done crime, what is the reason for a law against it?

Comment: @prakharlondhe You might as well ask why we bother with driver's licenses, when there's no way to automatically detect someone driving without one.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I agree.. but still Magical world was supposed to be more advanced then muggle?

Comment: @prakharlondhe by what standard? Technologically it is significantly *less* far advanced, owing to not needing technology for many things (and a lack of advanced scientific knowledge when most research efforts seem to go into magic). Magically, of course, it *is* infinitely more advanced, but that means does not automatically apply in all areas

Answer (score 10):

One thing we can say is that, if you Apparate without a license (a dangerous practise anyway, avoided even by many fully-qualified witches and wizards) you are quite likely to make a mess of it sooner or later. And when you do, you might find yourself in the lurch and require assistance from the Ministry of Magic ... who will fine you:

> 'You have to pass a test to Apparate?' Harry asked.
>
> 'Oh yes,' said Mr Weasley, tucking the tickets safely into the back pocket of his jeans. 'The Department of Magical Transportation had to fine a couple of people the other day for Apparating without a licence. It's not easy, Apparition, and when it's not done properly it can lead to nasty complications. This pair I'm talking about went and splinched themselves.'
>
> ...
>
> 'They left half of themselves behind,' said Mr Weasley, now spooning large amounts of treacle onto his porridge. 'So, of course, they were stuck. Couldn't move either way. Had to wait for the Accidental Magic Reversal Squad to sort them out. Meant a fair old bit of paperwork, I can tell you, what with the Muggles who spotted the body parts they'd left behind ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.63 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 6, *The Portkey*

Comment: Beat you to it, sorry :-)